# How to wire a switch with multiple lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I have 3 lights (Power is coming in the first light) that are [image]each on a single switch (in the same circuit). I want to put the 3 of them on the same switch. I found this helpful diagram but my switch is at the beginning of the circuit. How should I wire it?

Comment: I take it you mean that power is coming to the location of the switch first when you say "my switch is at the beginning of the circuit"

Comment: Don't look for a diagram for a 3-light circuit, look for a diagram for wiring 1 light where you have power->switch->light. Then extend the wiring to the other lights.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's the set up you need only need to run cable for 3rd light.